# A List inside of a Dictionary of Dictionaries is not appending values correctly

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, iteration, nested-lists

I'm working on a large project for predicting stock prices and it includes lists of integers within a dictionary nested in another dictionary. A little puzzling :)

The problem is that whenever I attempt to make a value of one list a different integer, it does it for the entire dictionary of lists. I'll include a sample code and the issue below

```
for k,v in equities_and_value.items():
    stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary[k]={0 : [v]}
for i in stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary:
    for x in range(0,runs): 
        stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary[i][x] = stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary[i][0]
    for y in range(0, years):
        stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary[i][y].append(0)
            

stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary["IBM"][0][1] = 500
```

the value of stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary before adding the 500:

```
{'IBM': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'MS': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'PEP': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}}
```

the value of stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary after adding the 500:

```
{'IBM': {0: [600, 500, 0], 1: [600, 500, 0], 2: [600, 500, 0]}, 'MS': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'PEP': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}}
```

The value I was hoping to get with the code:

```
{'IBM': {0: [600, 500, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'MS': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'PEP': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}}
```

I think it might have something to do with the lists being references of one object instead of separate variables as that was a solution to a similar problem. This code is just so many nested loops that the answer confused me so i'm looking for help here

Any solutions? thanks!

Comment: Right, there are multiple references to the same list. To get a (shallow) copy of a list, append `[:]` to the list or the variable containing the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary[i][x] = stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary[i][0]`, this doesn't copy the list. It makes each list point to the same memory address that the original list is stored in. So, when you change one list, you're changing the list in all the spots that point to that same memory address simultaneously. This is why the `[1]` index of all the arrays get changed to 500.

A workaround would be to create a hardcopy of the list and reassign it to `stocks_and_runs_total_dictionary["IBM"][0]`

```py
a = {'IBM': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'MS': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}, 'PEP': {0: [600, 0, 0], 1: [600, 0, 0], 2: [600, 0, 0]}}`

copyDesiredList = list(a['IBM'][0])
copyDesiredList[1] = 500
a['IBM'][0] = copyDesiredList
```

This would return your desired output.

Comment: got it! Thanks for the help